# Tailable Cursor example in Java using 3.0 driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

Can someone please provide a complete tailable cursor example in Java?  I am using the 3.0 driver and all examples appear to be 2.x.  I have only mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar in my classpath.  I want to get all documents as they are inserted in my capped collection.

```
//this does not work...
MongoCollection<BasicDBObject> col = database.getCollection(colName, BasicDBObject.class);
DBCursor cur = col.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("$natural", 1))
.addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_TAILABLE)
.addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA);


// And this does not work...
BasicDBObjectBuilder builder = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start();
builder.add("messageType","STATUS_REQUEST");
DBObject searchQuery = builder.get();
DBObject sortBy = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$natural", 1).get();
BasicDBObjectBuilder builderForFields = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start();
DBObject fields = builderForFields.get();
DBCursor cursor = new DBCursor(col, searchQuery, fields, ReadPreference.primary()  );
cursor.sort(sortBy);
cursor.addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA);
cursor.addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_TAILABLE);

//this does work but only returns the messageNumber field. I need the doc.
  MongoCursor<Long> c = database.getCollection(colName).distinct("messageNumber", Long.class).iterator();
```

I see that the MongoCursor interface was added in 3.0.  What is that for and does it replace DBCursor?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

A bit late to the party, but in case you still need help:

```
find(query).projection(fields).cursorType(CursorType.TailableAwait).iterator();
```

That code applies to the `MongoCollection` class.

CursorType is an enum and it has the following values:

```
Tailable
TailableAwait
```

Corresponding to the old DBCursor addOption Bytes types:

```
Bytes.QUERYOPTION_TAILABLE
Bytes.QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you might be looking for - EVENT Streaming in MongoDB 3.0.* using new api i.e. 3.0.2

```
Document query = new Document(); \\here use { indexedField: { $gt: <lastvalue> } index is not used(except for auto deleting documents) but created in capped collection
Document projection = new Document();
MongoCursor<Document> cursor= mongocollection.find(query).projection(projection).cursorType(CursorType.TailableAwait).iterator();  //add .noCursorTimeout(true) here to avoid timeout if you are working on big data

while (cursor.hasNext()){
    Document doc = cursor.next();
    //do what you want with doc
}
```

This way mongo cursor will check for new entries in capped collection

Comment: Is there a timeout for the cursor?

Comment: @user320550 There is a default timeout. To avoid timing out add this to the cursor - 
.noCursorTimeout(true) 
So now

MongoCursor<Document> cursor= mongocollection.find(query).projection(projection).noCursorTimeout(true) .cursorType(CursorType.TailableAwait).iterator();

Comment: Thank you. How have you implemented this practically? Do you have a separate thread which keeps on running this code to find any new entries to the mongo oplog?

Answer (score 0):

In your last line, replace `.distinct("messageNumber", Long.class)` with `.find()`.

[`distinct(String fieldName, Class<TResult> resultClass)`](https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#distinct-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) returns only the unique values of the one field you request.

[`find()`](https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#find--) returns all documents of the collection with all of their fields.

Comment: This does not appear to make it tailable.  How is that done in v3?  Before there was DBCursor.addOption(...)